# Turning a raw XMLHttpRequest or XDomainRequest into a jQuery Deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Is it possible to turn a *raw* XMLHttpRequest or XDomainRequest into a jQuery Deferred object (or wrap it in a jQuery Deferred object)?

When I say *raw*, I mean the object is created directly using `new XMLHttpRequest()` or `new XDomainRequest()`, not using jQuery's convenience functions (`$.ajax`, `$.get`, etc.)

I am trying to do this because in my page, there is an XMLHttpRequest (or XDomainRequest) that is created manually before jQuery is loaded, and then I want to turn it into a Deferred object and use in a `$.when` call once jQuery is loaded:

```
// raw XMLHttpRequest created here, with onreadystatechange attached.
window.my_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// ...
window.my_request.send();

// Load jQuery, using head.js or require.js
head.js(
    '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js',
    '//mydomain/my-script.js'
);

// Inside my-script.js, I want to turn window.my_request into
// a jQuery Deferred object and use it in a $.when call.
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but I think you have to wait for jQuery to load before you make your request in order to wrap it within a Deferred object.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like this to give you a promise which is a very crude emulation of a jQuery.ajax promise.

```
window.my_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// ...
window.my_request.send();

// Load jQuery, using head.js or require.js
head.js(
    '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js',
    '//mydomain/my-script.js'
);

// ...

var dfrd = $.Deferred();

window.my_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (window.my_request.readyState==4) {
        if (window.my_request.status==200) {
        //or possibly
        //if (window.my_request.status >= 200 && window.my_request.status < 300 || window.my_request.status === 304) {
            dfrd.resolve(window.my_request.responseText, window.my_request.statusText, window.my_request);
        }
        else (
            dfrd.reject(window.my_request, window.my_request.statusText);
        )
    }
}

window.my_request_promise = dfrd.promise();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's why I did not want to propose this as a solution.

Comment: @plalx, "that's why ..."; what is "that"?

Answer (score 0):

Well I've just looked at the source and unfortunately they haven't modularized the process of wrapping an `XMLHttpRequest` object and the process seems to be encapsulated within the `$.ajax` function itself.

Have a look at [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js) starting at line 428 to see how they are wrapping it.

You will have to *wrap* it yourself unfortunately.

*Note: I would rather have a look at the reasons you need an `XMLHttpRequest` object to be instanciated before jQuery gets loaded to make sure it isin't simply a design issue.*